# Метасимволы \b и \B

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

Текст:

```
cat catter scat scatter

nine-digit - nine - digit
```

Регулярные выражения:

1. `\bcat\b` — [результат](https://regex101.com/r/jC5oT8/1),
2. `\Bcat\B` — [результат](https://regex101.com/r/jC5oT8/2),

Всё, как в описании метасимволов: `\b` — соответствует границе слова, `\B` — не соответствует.

Однако если вместо `cat` использовать литерал `-`:

3. `\b-\b` — [результат](https://regex101.com/r/jC5oT8/3),
4. `\B-\B` — [результат](https://regex101.com/r/jC5oT8/4).

Получается наоборот. Шаблоном `\b-\b` находятся дефисы внутри слова, а `\B-\B` — окружённые пробелами. Почему так?

Comment: Очевидно, сам дефис не считается за часть слова

Comment: Проще всего понять что такое граница слова так: https://regex101.com/r/jC5oT8/5 и https://regex101.com/r/jC5oT8/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что символ `-` не является частью «слова» в терминологии PCRE.

В [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.escape.php) PHP к символьному классу `\w` есть следующие строки:

> Символ, образующий "слово" - это произвольная цифра, буква или символ подчеркивания, проще говоря, любой символ, который может являться частью "слова" в Perl.

А в [документации](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) к PCRE есть вот такое определение «слова»:

> A "word" character is an underscore or any character that is  a  letter or  digit.

Answer (score 2):

"nine-digit" - это не одно слово, а два. Вот по их границами и происходит отсечение.
Символ "-" не относится к символам, из которых состоят слова.